# 'Tribe' object has no attribute 'tribe_id'

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms

I have a view which should redirect the user to the new tribe that he created. but I don't know how to get the tribe_id for it to work.

**views.py**

```
def tribeview(request, tribe_id):
    tribe = get_object_or_404(Tribe,pk=tribe_id)
    playlist = tribe.playlist_set.all()
    context = {  'tribe': tribe, 'playlists':playlist }
    return render(request, 'app/tribe.html', context)


class create_tribe(CreateView):
    model = Tribe
    form_class = TribeForm
    template_name = 'app/create_tribe.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        tribe = form.save(commit=False)
        tribe.chieftain = self.request.user
        tribe.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('app:tribe-view', args={'tribe': self.object.tribe_id})
```

**urls.py**

```
app_name = 'app'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('tribe/<int:tribe_id>',views.tribeview,name='tribe-view'),
    path('tribe/<int:tribe_id>/playlist/<int:playlist_id>',views.playlistview,name='playlist-view'),
    path('new_tribe', login_required(create_tribe.as_view()), name="new-tribe"),
]
```

**models.py**

```
class Tribe(TimeStamped):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200,unique=True)
    chieftain = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    tribe_members = models.ManyToManyField(Member)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name[:80]
```

Comment: What's should be the field `tribe_id` on `Tribe` model instance? Looks like you need `Tribe` id field: `args={'tribe': self.object.id}`

Comment: Thanks that was the correct answer, I also needed to delete 'tribe': because it would be a dictonary instead of a id.